# Problems in building a Matlab .Net project

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to build a C# application which uses a Matlab library built using
[Matlab Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/dotnetbuilder/ug/bp94ar4-1.html). I've referenced both MWArray.dll and the Matlab-generated dll, but I still get get the following error message:

> The type or namespace name 'MWMCR' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

More info:

- I'm using VS2010 with the .NET 4 framework.
- The Matlab dll was not built by me, and I'm not sure which Matlab version nor which .Net Framework it requires (could this be the issue?)

Comment: Have you installed the (correct) Matlab Runtime on your machine.

Comment: @Noffls - I've installed the MCR which came bundled with the dll. The Matlab coder used Matlab's deploytool

Answer (score 0):

You said you referenced the dlls, but didn't say precisely where you referenced them.  I had a similar issue the first time I attempted to get a MATLAB dll from Builder NE working within a C# project.  Ultimately, it turned out that simply referencing the MATLAB dlls from within the .NET assembly that made use of them was insufficient.  It wasn't until I referenced the MATLAB dlls at the top level of the project that they actually loaded at runtime and things started working as expected.  Give it a try.  Add a reference to the dlls at the top level of the project.